# Logarithmic Scale Slider for GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm having trouble to create a slider for GUI in MATLAB. I
really want a slider that ranges from 10^-1 to 10^-5. But that
has intervals by factors of 0.1. So the the slider would
have a logarithmic scale. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: The closest you'll be able to come in base MATLAB is to use the linear values of the slider as the powers. Non-linear slider scales aren't available in MATLAB, you'd likely need to dig into the underlying Java to find something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understood you right. If you want to make logarithmic scale from linear scale:

Definition of logarithm:

[image]

So if you need to slider from 10^-1 to 10^-5 you want to get from your slider some value and convert it properly. I suggest to set your `min` and `max` to 1 and 5 (or -5 and -1) and after  every slider callback or just use of slider value  convert using this equation:

```
y = 10^(-x)
```

Where `y` is your wanted value and `x` is a value in a slider. 
In a code it should be similar to this:

```
logValue = 10^(-get(hObject,'Value'));
set(handles.text2,'string',logValue);
```

Check this method by putting in your gui some kind of text box that would show you your `y`.

But if you want to make linear scale from logarithmic:

```
 y = log(x)
```